# Injecting UI in ASP.NET- MVC using UNITY 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container, ioc-container, unity2.0

I am using UNITY 2.0 with MVC 3.

I have injected  types using the container into MVC.net solution.
All this while the types were non-UI component.How can I inject a type which has UI ?

The solution i can think of is to write UI rendering Code somethign like following and wrap it with a C# Type.

```
class HTMLHelper    
{   
    string spitTable()   
    {    
        string strUITable = "<Table><TR><TD><TD></TR></Table>";      
        return strUITable ;   
    }   
}
```

Is it correct way of doing thing ? Any one having better solution ?

Iam using ASP.NET MVC and still prefer to use the shtml files :)

Comment: If you are writing HTML in C#, I would recommend either using TagBuilder or a library like HtmlTags. https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/htmltags You gain a lot of advantages of composability if you do it right and you never have to worry about forgetting to close a tag.

Comment: But the question remains, is there a UNITY way to make my web UI composite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got my answer , it's WCSF(web client software factory).
also look for 'Composite web UI application block'.

http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/

also look into

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blaine/archive/2010/03/22/will-wcsf-vs-2010-version-support-unity-2-0-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx